# protocol method not being entered when called from delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I am having some issues with my protocol & delegate that I have set up in my app.
I am trying to return some data from a class back to a viewcontroller, however when I try to send it back nothing happens... The protocol method is never entered.

I have been over the way  have set it up several times using [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) as a reference and just cannot see where I am making the error, So I thought if I share my code maybe someone here might be able to see what I cannot.

Heres the code I have written.

**SendingClass.h**

```
@protocol SearchViewCachedData <NSObject>
- (void)sendMyArray:(NSArray *)array;
@end
//..
    __weak id <SearchViewCachedData> SearchViewDelegate;
//..
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id <SearchViewCachedData> SearchViewDelegate;
//..
```

**SendingClass.m**

```
@synthesize SearchViewDelegate;

//..

[[self SearchViewDelegate]sendMyArray:dictionaryArray];
```

**SearchView.h**

```
@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <SearchViewCachedData> {
```

**SearchView.m**

```
- (void)sendMyArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    //Break point in here.. but its never reached.
}
```

Going abit bonkers here so any help what so ever would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you instantiate and assign your `SearchViewController` (Or whatever other object implements this protocol)? Also, naming your properties and variables starting with a capital letter  can make your code tougher to understand as convention specifies starting with lowercase. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling your delegate is not set

Check to make sure searchViewDelegate is set to an instance value

```
if (self.searchViewDelegate != nil) {
    [self.searchViewDelegate sendArray:array];
}
```

Also. Properties should have their first case lower case. Classes are the items that are Capitalized.

**amendment**

It may be getting set to nil by another part in code or you may not be setting it at all.

where you synthesize your delegate you can create a setter as well.

```
@synthesize searchViewDelegate = _searchViewDelegate;
- (void) setSearchViewDelegate:(id<SearchViewCachedData>) searchViewDelegate{
    if (searchViewDelegate != searchViewDelegate){ // Add breakpoint here to see when set is called.
        searchViewDelegate = searchViewDelegate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the if and step through. I imagine your variable is nil

Comment: where should I put this piece of code sorry.. my brain is falling to bits been on this problem alone for 3 hours...

Comment: put it where you call your sendArray: method, and use it to test if your delegate is populated. If its nil then it will not hit the sendArray: method. it will skip over it.

Comment: Essentially this is a standard if to test validity of the object. If it is nil, it would not complain, it would just send the message to nil. and any message to nil results in nil. Therefore this bug will hide.

Comment: right.. so I added the code in, and put a break point before and inside the if statment and its never entered.. which means its populated right?? :P

Comment: no. If you added this code to the point where you call your delegate, then added breakpoints to before and inside the if, and it did not hit the breakpoint, then your app never even tried to execute the code, therefore you have more issues than a nil delegate. You should look further up the code chain to find out what else is stopping it from hitting the delegate.

Comment: I will attempt to explain it better "I put the if statment right before **[[self SearchViewDelegate]sendMyArray:dictionaryArray];** I added two break points one before the if statement and one inside the if statement. The first break point was "hit" for lack of a better tearm but the second break point inside the if statement was never "hit""

Comment: that means your delegate is nil. it was never set. therefore any messages you sent to it would be instead sent to nil. sending a message to nil, returns nil. nil is == to void or FALSE or NO

Comment: oh okay.. So now I need to figure out why its not being set... I just dont get it, I have done everything I can think of but I have no idea why it would be getting set to nil...

Comment: oh okay, thanks very much for taking your time with me.. Just trying to do this core data stuff thats ont related to this question but is the reason for this me needing to do this has made my week a living hell.. lol

Comment: so I have tried your new example.. I'm not sure if its telling you anything about my issue however that method you told me to write in never gets entered.

Comment: that tells me that the delegate has never been set. do you have any place in code that puts a value into that property ?

Comment: @property..... your delegate must be set somewhere. It will not magically have the value you want it to have.

Comment: Oh, In my header file I am doing this **@property (weak, nonatomic) id <searchViewCachedData> searchViewDelegate;**

Comment: That is a property. It does not set itself. You will need to set the property. with a class that conforms to the protocol. SearchViewCachedData which by the way should be capitalized. I am out of the office for the night tho. good luck.

Comment: Thanks Volure you have been a great help i'll let you know how I go.

Comment: nope not yet.. I went to bed an hour or so after you and I spoke.. I am getting back into it now.. had to have a break to try and get a fresh perspective on it :P

Comment: found the problem.. I had not called **[sendingClass setSearchViewDelegate:self];**

Comment: That is what I was imagining. Glad you were able to get it all sorted out.

Comment: Cool thanks for all the help.. I must have just been over tired to miss that one.. I just couldn't think straight.